# Browser push notifications only on logged in | Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was implementing Firebase Browser push notifications in a React Project,
But I want the browser push notifications to come only when the user is logged in to the my website or application.
My **requirement** is:

1. Send Browser notifications to the user who are **signed in**, with their name, and some other details.
2. For the users **not signed in**, a generic message should go to them.

My service-worker file and the push-notifications file is as follows:

push-notifications.js

```
    import firebase from 'firebase';

    export const initializeFirebase = () => {
      firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "xxx",
      authDomain: "xxx",
      projectId: "xxx",
      storageBucket: "xxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxx",
      appId: "xxx",
      measurementId: "xxx"
    });
     const messaging = firebase.messaging();
     messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
     console.log("Loading...",payload);
     alert("Firebase is awesome");
    });

    }

    export const askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications = async () => {
     try {
       const messaging = firebase.messaging();
       await messaging.requestPermission();
       const token = await messaging.getToken();
       console.log('token: ', token);
       return token;
      } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
     }
    }

   export const getMessagingToken = async () => {
     try {
       const messaging = firebase.messaging();
       const token = await messaging.getToken({vapidKey:   
   "xxx"});
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    }
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log(messaging);
```

Everything is working fine, but I want to send the notifications only to the users that have currently logged in to the website.
And some notifications to the users that are not logged in to the application.
I am not able to find any resource on firebase offical site for the same.

It would be great help if you share any relevant resources or answer the way to complete the requirement. 
Thanks in advance!
Feel free to ask in case of any queries.

Comment: Add an additional clause where you check if the current user has been authenticated. According to the result of that check you can then deliver the appropriate message..

Comment: The browser notifications are sent even if the site is not currently opened, so that is my question, how to detect whether the user is logged in or not even if the site is closed.

Comment: Haven't you implemented an auth-method for users yet? How do you handle user registration and logging-in?

Comment: I have implemented, my question is how to do I detect if the user is logged in or not, if the browser is closed?

Comment: let say, my jwt token is present in the browser local storage. Now how to get that if the browser is closed.

Comment: you could keep the ttl/expiration of the jwt really low and only refresh token when the user is actually requesting content..